# Catalina make the Xcode Simulator to freeze, lag and work slow

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, lag, macos-catalina, tvos-simulator

I was using Sierra for a while and the Xcode simulator works well - fast and furious. After updating to Catalina (why the hell i did that :( ) - xcode simulator started to work very slow. Especially animation. Especially for tvOS.

I using MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012).

Why and how to fix that?

P.S. Slow animations is switched off. Graphics quality override is Low Quality.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of most reports.  In fact, the Simulator had major performance improvements in Catalina.  iOS 13+ uses the GPU for rendering as Metal is available in those configurations.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia updated the info about my machine. Maybe it's bug for this type of macbook only. Contact me if you need additional info.

Comment: Please do file a feedback report for this. It would be helpful to get an Instruments System Trace taken while you are experiencing this slowness. A second pass with a video recording will also help (but for perf reasons I suggest taking the trace with everything else quit and no video recording going). If you post the FB number here we can take a look.